# difference between "on campus" and "at campus"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, prepositions, usage

I am Korean Enlish learner:)

I want to know the difference between "on campus" and "at campus" .

I'm not sure when to put preposition 'on' and 'at' before ' campus'.

I am curious about the usage becuse my teacher said we can use both "at" and "on" with the word "school".

Comment: I've found these grammar rules https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/at-on-and-in-place that recommend the use of "at" with school/college/university "campus" seems to be an exception. Maybe some English native speaker may help us

Comment: Ey, Belle, I've obtained this answer for you in the "Senior" site https://english.stackexchange.com/a/446673/217656 We got a lot to study there. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commonest preposition I have read and used is *'on'* with *campus.* That said, *on campus* or *on a campus* sounds fine. But, *on the campus* seems a little strange to me.

On the other hand, 'the campus' is possible but I'd then change the preposition - *at the campus* to denote that we are talking about a *specific or definite campus.* Additionally, *at campus* sounds very strange, and I'm not sure whether it's correct! [N-gram for all this.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20the%20campus%2C%20at%20campus%2C%20on%20the%20campus%2C%20on%20campus%2C%20on%20a%20campus&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20a%20campus%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Take a look here https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/at-on-and-in-place According to these rule, shouldn't be "at"? "with school/college/university"

Comment: @RubioRic - The usage of prepositions with "campus" are not the same as with "school," even though the two words are related. I agree with this answer: _on campus_ (most usual), _on the campus_ or _at the campus_ (both acceptable), _at campus_ (rare, except perhaps in phrases like, "Security may be present at campus events", but that's because the preposition is being determined by the word _events_, not _campus_).

Comment: @J.R. I'm not trying to disqualify this answer (already upvoted) but to find a rule. So both are acceptable but "on" is commonest. All right.

Answer (score 1):

I don't ever think I've heard the term "at campus". I've only used "on campus" for years, so I think you should be okay only using that.

### Examples

- I went to the event on campus.
- There are on-campus apartments available for rent.
- Yes, there are fast-food restaurants on campus.
- Are you on campus right now?
- The lecture hall is on campus.

### Other related examples

- Can you please drive me to campus?
- I'm headed to campus right now.